# Wp-admin page not found following copy of site

Tags: admin

I have used WP Clone to copy my site from http://www.iwillbeawebdeveloper.co.uk/blog to http://www.iwillbeawebdeveloper.co.uk. The site has been cloned but I cannot log in.

Whenever I go to wp-admin I get an error message saying "Error establishing a database connection"

Any ideas please?

James

Comment: Upon further investigation, it seems it is an issue with my host.  Please close this question.

Comment: i just checked your site and it still looks like the issues are there that i described below...

Answer (score 0):

I've never used wp-clone so i'll try to help based on what i see.  D

id you change the site url and wordpress?  When i load your site, css isn't loading either which generally means you haven't done that yet.

First make sure that your wp-config that you've got the right database.

You need to go into your new database and change the site url and home url to the new address.  I suggest not doing this through phpmyadmin though as it will cause some problems.

Go get this tool: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Upload it into your www/ folder. (I usually rename the search and replace folder to SRDB.)

now navigate to your site with the SRDB at the end.  (www.example.com/SRDB)and the top two lines you'll see a search field and a replace field. (if you get a db connection error here, double check the wp-config to ensure that it has the right credentials).  In the search place your old site address: http://www.iwillbeawebdeveloper.co.uk/blog

in the replace field place your new url http://www.iwillbeawebdeveloper.co.uk/

hit live live run.

ONLY do this after ensuring you're on your new url and that it's loaded into your new database.

This should fix your problems!